# Stack Overflow h-index metric?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was wondering whether having an "h-index" like metric for users would be interesting to have.

For those who have never heard of this term, "h-index" in academia is the metric for an academic for defining productivity and impact of his/her publications. `h` is defined as the number of published papers with citations for each at least `h` times.

I was wondering whether such metric in Stack Overflow will be interesting to have. "h-index" in Stack Overflow, therefore, is defined as `h` answers each of which having at least `h` upvotes.

How will this metric defer from the current reputation metric? Well, I think that h-index will reveal the impact of a user and the quality of his/her answers at the same time. Not that such feature is necessary, but I thought it will be interesting to discuss since meta is for discussion and ideas.

Comment: I think it would be really fun to have h-index here.

Comment: On a tangential note, it shouldn't be difficult to get an h-index with a SEDE query. I predict such a query will be posted here shortly...

Comment: @duplode that will be interesting!

Comment: @duplode The duplicate has that [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45195/what-is-my-h-index).

Comment: This is really great! Thanks @user2285236

Comment: @user2285236 I hadn't opened that link. Good find, thanks!

Comment: I would think a better analogue to h-index would be something like the number of answers to questions which are the target of `h` duplicates (since that is in effect a citation).

Comment: [Here are a few SEDE queries for generating h-index rankings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369548/2751851).

Answer (score 3):

We already have the "Impact" metric publicly available for all users.  The issue with this metric is that it's fuzzy at best, as it does factor in things like question view and answer score, but it can be gamed to be exaggerated to uselessness.

So yes, this likely already exists and I'd want to consider it [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but I don't believe it to be particularly *useful*, since it's not something that I've really bothered looking at for any one individual contributor for any meaningful data point.

Comment: This impact however is not about the answer quality and productivity. The h index defined above shows a user with constant contribution and with quality answers.

Comment: That "impact" metric is arguably the most useless stat on a user's profile. While the intention of it was fine, the implementation of it is completely broken and useless to the point of being misleading. I have no idea why they picked that particular formula when there are so many other better options. IIRC, SE made a meta post asking for feedback about it, and almost everything else was better, yet they decided to stick with their broken one...

Comment: @Rafael:  Once you get any *one* person electing not to downvote a post for any reason, discussions about accurate metrics of "quality" fly right out the window.

Comment: @Mysticial:  It'd probably be easier it if just went away, tbh.  I've never really looked at it or cared all that much about it except when it was first launched.  It's fluff.

Comment: @Makoto That is actually a good point.